# add or remove payment gateways based on cart total amount in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, cart

I have a plugin that adds a fee when **authorize.net** is used as the payment gateway.

However, when I use a gift card that covers the entire purchase and brings the cart total down to $0, the order is still set to authorize.net and there's a fee when the customer isn't technically paying for anything.

I'm using the following code to disable authorize.net payment gateway when the cart total is less than $0:

```
function authorize_less($available_gateways) {
    $maximum = 0;
    if ( WC()->cart->total < $maximum ) {
    unset( $available_gateways['authorizenet'] );
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'authorize_less' );



function authorize_more($available_gateways) {
    $maximum = 0;
    if ( WC()->cart->total > $maximum ) {
    unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'authorize_more' );
```

The function isn't working reliably. Either the credit card fee does not show up at all or requires a second refresh to appear or disappear based on what I do in the cart.

The issue is probably more than the auto calculation and in the function itself. there's probably a way to put it into one function rather than the two I have above, but I haven't had success with it

Answer (score 4):

Your both functions can be merged as follow and you are not targeting the zero cart total amount.

So you should try this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'conditional_available_payment_gateways' 20, 1 );
function conditional_available_payment_gateways( $available_gateways ) {
if( is_admin() ) return $available_gateways; // Only for frontend
    $amount_threshold = 0;

    if ( WC()->cart->total <= $amount_threshold ) {
        unset( $available_gateways['authorizenet'] );
    } else {
        unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (active theme).*

Untested, but it should work.

Comment: thank you, this code is definitely more compact. i'm still running into the issue where it takes a full refresh of the page for the condition to show in the calculation, is this now an AJAX issue?

Comment: @mnguyen I can replace 'authorizenet' by another gateway, but for testing on my side the problem is to "use a gift card": Is that gift card a coupon like or what? how the discount is maid? I think that the problem is there. You should better explain the process step by step in a timeline kind... Also you could try with `WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total( )` to see what happen…

Comment: i am using the fixed cart amount like a gift card and that amount can exceed the cart total. 

but since the problem is with the front end showing the new calculation based on this rule, what if instead of getting rid of a payment gateway, simply changing it based on the condition? i noticed that selecting the radio buttons does update the calculations as it should.

tried this, but it didn't work:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814998/select-woocommerce-payment-method-conditionally-in-php

also seeing suggestions to change the js file but feel like it's better done through php

Comment: @mnguyen Yes because it is ajax driven… When you select a checkbox it execute this JS `$('body').trigger('update_checkout');` as a lot of JS events are delegated to body… What I don't catch is how you set this fixed cart amount like, when and where on front end (which hook and where is the related code for that gift)… Without that details and code, I just get more stuck than you are.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps anyone, but I need to do a credit card authorization for eWay which allows you to get a recurring payment token.
However, if you cart balance would be zero, Woocommmerce doesn't show the credit card form.

Checking the source at `includes/wc-template-functions.php`, I found that the function `woocommerce_checkout_payment` applys a filter to see if payment is required.
Since this filter is never added, but just applied, I guess we can add it and it will get priority.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_payment', function(){
    return true;
  }, 99 );
```

With this in place it always shows the credit card form, even for zero balance. You can of course put more logic in the filter to decide to return true or false.

Hope this is helpful for someone, it was for me.